# Meaning of "exported from somewhere"

Tags: meaning, verbs, prepositions

I don't quite understand how one should use the expression "exported from somewhere". What does it mean when an item is exported from a given place?

So far I've always seen the verb *export* used like this:

> The UK **exports** veal **to** many European countries.

I've also seen the verb *import* being used like this:

> The UK **imports** asparagus **from** Bolivia.

But I don't understand what *exported from* means. For example:

> Wheat is **exported from** the UK.

Comment: Would you rather have us say "wheat is exported by the U.K."?

Comment: @Peter Shor: I think *"is exported by"* is just as valid, but *"is exported **from**"* is [three times more common](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+exported+by%2Cis+exported+from&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many verbs have complements that express a two-way flow, such as *import* and *export*, *give* and *receive*, or *send* and *receive*.

```
Ron gave Paul a new television.
Paul received a new television from Ron.
The new television was given by Ron.
The new television was a gift from Ron.


The ship sent a distress signal to shore.
The Coast Guard station received a distress signal from the ship.
The distress signal was sent by the ship.
```

These seem analogous to the three examples you wrote.  I agree that

*The UK exports wheat*.

is superior to

*Wheat is exported from the UK*.

but I still believe the latter is acceptable.

Comment: However the latter form makes much more sense than the former with multiple countries, eg. _Wheat is exported from Canada, Ukraine and the UK, but imported by France and Turkey_ (countries selected at random).

Answer (score 2):

‘Wheat is exported from the UK’ means that British wheat producers sell their crop to other countries. It is not necessary to specify which countries.